# REngine.CreateNumericVector returns "Value does not fall within the expected range" if called more than once

Tags: c#, r

I am trying to create a graph using RDotNet in a C# program.  I call a form which creates C# lists of doubles based on the input.  It then attempts to graph the lists against each other as X and Y values.  It always works the first time I call it, but if I call it again, my call to engine.CreateNumericVector results in the error "Value does not fall within the expected range".  The form is recreated every time it is called and new lists are created every time.  This happens even if I am calling it with the same data in the list.

Have tried calling CreateNumericVector with lists of differing size, but without plotting, and have no problem.  Have tried setting the list to an IEnumerable value and using that, does not work.  Have tried the same scenario passing in SymbolicExpressions to a routine that created R plots, with no trouble.  Have tried passing list parameters into the plot function instead of using global lists, doesn't matter. The problem seems to be with CreateNumericVector.

```
private void PlotR()
{
    using (engine)
    {
      NumericValue a = engine.CreateNumericValue(aList);
      engine.SetSymbol("AValues", a);

      NumericValue b = engine.CreateNumericValue(bList);
      engine.SetSymbol("BValues", b);

      engine.Evaluate("plot(BValues, AValues, psch = 15, cex=1, 
          col=rgb(0,0,1);
    }
}
```

Bring up the form, create the lists of doubles, and call this function once, and it plots the values.  Close the form, bring it up again with different information, creating different lists, always stops the line: NumericValue a = engine.CreateNumericValue(aList) with the error "Value does not fall within the expected range.  REngine is created successfully early in the program, before any forms are called, so the engine is running continuously through all this, with no trouble.  This form is the only one that uses it.

Comment: Not sure why the code showed up so weirdly.  It starts with private void PlotR()